# How do I do a '$all $in' on mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, match

I have the following collection

```
>db.prueba.find({})
{ "_id" : "A", "requi" : null }
{ "_id" : "B", "requi" : null }
{ "_id" : "C", "requi" : [ "A" ] }
{ "_id" : "D", "requi" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "E", "requi" : [ "C" ] }
{ "_id" : "F", "requi" : [ "B", "D"] }
{ "_id" : "G", "requi" : [ "F" ] }
```

I need each element of the requi field to be in the following array. in this case, the array has only one element

```
["A", "D"]
```

When I use the operator `$all $in` returns the following

```
 >db.prueba.find({requi:{$elemMatch:{$in:['A','D']}}})
{ "_id" : "C", "requi" : [ "A" ] }
{ "_id" : "D", "requi" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "F", "requi" : [ "B", "D" ] }
```

the query must returns only document, because `'B'` not exists in the array `["A" , "D"]`

```
{ "_id" : "C", "requi" : [ "A" ] }
```

please, help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) to check whether the given array is set of the `requi` array and then [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to eliminate the non-matched ones.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "requi": { "$ne": null } } },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$eq": [{ "$setIsSubset": ["$requi", ["A", "D"]] }, true] },
      "then": "$$DESCEND",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```